# Reset Password Link Joomla - While in "maintenance mode" / offline mode

Tags: joomla

How do users reset passwords while in "off-line" mode.
We are running the site as Intranet.

Joomla 2.5.4

Comment: Users wont be able to access the site to reset their password unless they have admin rights. Even if you created a link redirecting them to the "reset password" page, still wouldn't work.

Comment: I understood that part - that's why I am looking for a workaround. There has to be way to modify some files to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mhm.. this is quite long to do, but maybe you can work it out.

1. Grant your user level offline access (you can do that in Global configuration -> Permissions)
2. Create a menu entry that point to the user profile and set visible to your users
3. Set every menu/modules etc etc invisible to "normal" users (except the previous one)

I've never tried it before, but it should work.

Comment: This sounds like a workable solution indeed, I am going to give it a try. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to share my solution for Joomla 3.9:
In the file "offline.php" of your template (or in /templates/system if the template has no offline.php) you can place this code before where the login form is displayed:

```
if( JRequest::getVar('option') == 'com_users') {
    ?><jdoc:include type="message"/><?php 
    $registrationController = new UsersController();
    $registrationController->display();
} else {
    // Login Form
}
```

so it displays the dialogs to reset the password if the page is loaded by using "index.php?option=com_users&task=request.reset" or similar, but shows the "offline" login form by default.